# Spring security: REST with MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Im **begginer** in spring security! I have MVC + REST application written on Spring Boot. I have a code for securing my app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(
                SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .securityMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize.requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ROOT")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(basic ->
                basic.authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, exp)->
                        response.setStatus(401)))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain formFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize.requestMatchers("/login*", "/web-res/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(form ->
                form.loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error"))
            .logout(logout ->
                logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
            .build();
    }
}
```

Thats work fine, but when i trying getting data from MVC (that was authorized with `formFilterChain`) with `ajax` to `/api/**` (that controls by `apiFilterChain`) - i need use basic auth.
How i can fix that to take data from `/api/**` with authorized by form login method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method after reading documentation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final Customizer<AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>
            .AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry> securedRequests = authorize -> {
        authorize.requestMatchers("/login*", "/web-res/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ROOT")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    };

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(
                SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(securedRequests)
            // checking for "Authorization" header
            .securityMatcher(request ->
                request.getHeader("Authorization") != null)
            .httpBasic(basic ->
                basic.authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, exp)->
                        response.setStatus(401)))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain formFilterChain(
            HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(securedRequests)
            .formLogin(form ->
                form.loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error"))
            .logout(logout ->
                logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
            .build();
    }
}
```

First filter will working if request has header "Authorization"

```
// checking for "Authorization" header
...
.securityMatcher(request ->
  request.getHeader("Authorization") != null)
...
```

If header "Authorization" not found - then executing `formFilterChain`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).